# Is it possible to create a link to start an Office Communicator conversation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, office-communicator-2007

I was wondering if it was possible to start a new Office Communicator conversation from a link in the same way that you can start start a new email with the "MAILTO:" link.  I am mostly looking to do this from within Outlook 2010.

Comment: Actually, sip:you@domain.com not serves the need. i have created a hyperlinlik like this *<A href="sip:you@domain.com"> Ping Me </A>"* the problem is, instaead of opening a window with my name and the initiators name for chat, it says like *"Microsoft Office Communicator is Already Running"* Is thr any reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the format
sip:you@domain.com

This works correctly for me

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the SIP: uri mentioned from bquaresma, if you have telephone integration, you can also use the tel: uri to make a phone call.  In my outlook signature, I have my phone number as tel:+15551234567  Outlook just shows it as 55501234567.  When people click on it, it initiates a phone call to me.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I'll be sure to keep this in mind when our phone integration starts up next year.